# useState on React Hooks not updating Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have tried many things and can't seem to understand why setTypes won't update the 'types' array??

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { PostList } from './post-list';
import * as api from '../utils/api';

export const PostSelector = (props) => {
  const [posts, setPosts]     = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [type, setType]       = useState('post');
  const [types, setTypes]     = useState([]);
  
  const fetchTypes = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await api.getPostTypes();
    delete response.data.attachment;
    delete response.data.wp_block;
    const postTypes = response.data;
    console.log(response.data); // {post: {…}, page: {…}, case: {…}}
    setTypes(postTypes);
    console.log(types); // []

    // Why types remain empty??
  }

const loadPosts = async (args = {}) => {
  const defaultArgs = { per_page: 10, type };
  const requestArgs = { ...defaultArgs, ...args };
  

  requestArgs.restBase = types[requestArgs.type].rest_base; // Cannot read property 'rest_base' of undefined
  
  const response = await api.getPosts(requestArgs);
  console.log(response.data);
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchTypes();
  loadPosts();
}, []);

  return (
    <div className="filter">
      <label htmlFor="options">Post Type: </label>
      <select name="options" id="options">
        { types.length < 1 ? (<option value="">loading</option>) : Object.keys(types).map((key, index) => <option key={ index } value={ key }>{ types[key].name }</option> ) }
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please, take a look at the console.log and notice the different responses.

What I am trying to do is to load list of types, in this case 'post', 'page' and 'case' and then render a list of posts based on the current 'type'. The default type is 'post'.

If I add [types] to useEffect. I finally get the values but the component renders nonstop.

Thanks to everyone for your comments. Multiple people have pointed out the problem, being that, the fact that we set the state doesn't mean it will set right away because it it asynchronous.

How do we solve this problem then? Regardless of the reasons, how do we get it done? How do we work with our state at any point in time and perform calculations based on our state if we don't know when it will become available? How do we make sure we wait whatever we need to and then use the values we expect?

Comment: Try using spread operator. `setTypes([...postTypes]);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but that returns the same results.

Comment: looks like response.data is an object, not an array

Comment: I'm not sure if `setTypes()` is async method. But try using await, `await setTypes([...postTypes]);`

Comment: Don't you receive any errors on `console.log`? It would also aggregate to the question to post them, if you receive any.

Comment: Thanks @GlenK. I tried adding an object as a default value of types, just to see if that would update the state, still won't work. Returns an empty object instead that an empty array.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderSantos. But no errors.

Comment: Thanks @boosted_duck tried with await, but with and without the spread operator, still same exact result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: This answers your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60294328/react-hooks-update-sort-of-whenever-they-feel-like-it/60294453#60294453

Comment: Thanks @ZainUlAbideen! The problem in this case is that types is an object so that causes useEffect to re-render forever.

Comment: Your welcome but I don't get it that how re-rendering is connected to types being object?

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen take a look at this: https://dev.to/karthick3018/common-mistake-done-while-using-react-hooks-1foj

Comment: @drjorgepolanco, Thanks, I hope you've read the comments in on this article ;) Glad it helped you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

For any one coming here and not being able to set/update a useState array you need to use a spread operator (...) and not just the array e.g. "[...initState]" instead of "initState" ... in Typescript

```
 //initialise
  const initState: boolean[] = new Array(data.length).fill(false);
  const [showTable, setShowTable] = useState<boolean[]>([...initState]);

  // called from an onclick to update
  const updateArray = (index: number) => {
    showTable[index] = !showTable[index];
    setShowTable([...showTable]);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like useState is asynchronous and does not update the value instantly after calling it.

[Review this same case here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

`useState`'s setTypes is an asynchronous function so the changes do not take effect immediately. You can use `useEffect` to check if anything changes

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const defaultArgs = { per_page: 10, type };
    const requestArgs = { ...defaultArgs, ...args };
    requestArgs.restBase = types;
    console.log("types updated",types)
},[types])
```

You can remove `loadPosts` because now useEffect will run whenever types change

Comment: If I pass [types] it never stops rendering.

Comment: That's strange. Can you provide some example code on https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-leukwv so I can test it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your types to be an array, yet you are passing a dictionary of dictionaries through to it.
Try this:

```
const [types, setTypes]     = useState({});
```

You also do not need to call

```
loadPosts()
```

becuase the useState hook will re-render your component, only updating what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ok, The short answer is due to [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

It not due to `asynchronous` as other answers said !!!

---

#### Solution (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞

You can check the changes by `console.log` at `return` function like this.

```
return (
    <div> Hello World! 
      {
        console.log(value) // this will reference every re-render
      } 
    </div>
  );
```

or create a new one useEffect with `value` as a dependency like below

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value); // this will reference every value is changed
  }, [value]);
```

```js
function App() {
  const [value, Setvalue] = React.useState([]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Setvalue([1, 2, 3]);
    console.log(value); // this will reference to value at first time
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div> Hello World! 
      {
        console.log(value) // this will reference every re-render
      } 
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Read here in more detail: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @drjorgepolanco