# Why do the console.logs and UI in my React app not show the same state variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

In this [coin flipping program](https://codesandbox.io/s/flipcoin-zj9sl?file=/src/App.js:0-1130), there is a delay in the updated state.flipResult and state.coinURL variables being printed to console (they are always a click behind what is shown in the UI).

I'm sure it has something to do with setState updates being asynchronous. How then, can I "force" a state update and rerender?

I've seen examples of passing prevState to the setState function in order to force an update to a counter, for instance, but in this instance the flipResult and coinURL ( both "heads" or "tails") are not based on the previous state. I could find a way to toggle between heads and tails using prevState, but I might also want, in future, to "force" an instant state update based on a user's input or selection, unrelated to previous state. Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    flipResult: "",
    coinURL: ""
  };

  flipCoin = () => {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    if (number <= 50) {
      this.setState( { flipResult: "heads", coinURL: "heads" });
    } else if (number >= 51) {
      this.setState({ flipResult: "tails", coinURL: "tails" });
    }
    console.log("flipResult is " + this.state.flipResult);
    console.log("flipResult is " + this.state.coinURL);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <h2> Flip a coin! </h2>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.flipCoin}> Flip! </button>
        <br />

        {this.state.flipResult ? (
          <div>
            The result is {this.state.flipResult}.
            <br />
            <br />
            <img
              src={`./img/${this.state.coinURL}.jpg`}
              alt="coin"
              style={{ width: "200px", height: "auto" }}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div> No result yet! </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Web app can be found here - https://codesandbox.io/s/flipcoin-zj9sl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It may be due to `Closure`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291964/usestate-on-react-hooks-not-updating-array/67582886#67582886

Comment: You don't need or want to force any state updates. React knows when to update, but `setState` is not synchronous, so your `console.log`s are going to show the wrong values. See [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are not understanding that `setState` is an asynchronous event, therefore you can not trust that calling `console.log(this.state.SOMETHING)` will give you the new state.

the function `setState` accepts as second parameter a callback function, so you can do something like this:

```
flipCoin = () => {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    if (number <= 50) {
      this.setState( { flipResult: "heads", coinURL: "heads" }, this.logInformation);
    } else if (number >= 51) {
      this.setState({ flipResult: "tails", coinURL: "tails" }, this.logInformation);
    }
    
};

logInformation(){
  console.log("flipResult is " + this.state.flipResult);
  console.log("flipCoin is " + this.state.coinURL);
}
```

so after the state has been set, it will call your function and you will be able to see the new state.

NOTE:
notice that when you click for the first time it shows empty, on the second click it will show the previous state, this is because as I explained, it is showing the unset value.

the whole code you posted would be the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    flipResult: "",
    coinURL: ""
  };

  flipCoin = () => {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    if (number <= 50) {
      this.setState( { flipResult: "heads", coinURL: "heads" }, this.logInformation);
    } else if (number >= 51) {
      this.setState({ flipResult: "tails", coinURL: "tails" }, this.logInformation);
    }
    
  };

  logInformation(){
    console.log("flipResult is " + this.state.flipResult);
    console.log("flipCoin is " + this.state.coinURL);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <h2> Flip a coin! </h2>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.flipCoin}> Flip! </button>
        <br />

        {this.state.flipResult ? (
          <div>
            The result is {this.state.flipResult}.
            <br />
            <br />
            <img
              src={`./img/${this.state.coinURL}.jpg`}
              alt="coin"
              style={{ width: "200px", height: "auto" }}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div> No result yet! </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied

So you can put console log in callback like this:

```
  this.setState({ flipResult: "heads", coinURL: "heads" }, () => {
    console.log("flipResult is " + this.state.flipResult);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    flipResult: "",
    coinURL: ""
  };

  flipCoin = async () => {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    if (number <= 50) {
      await this.setState( { flipResult: "heads", coinURL: "heads" });
    } else if (number >= 51) {
      await this.setState({ flipResult: "tails", coinURL: "tails" });
    }
    console.log("flipResult is " + this.state.flipResult);
    console.log("flipcoin png  is " + this.state.coinURL);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <h2> Flip a coin! </h2>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.flipCoin}> Flip! </button>
        <br />

        {this.state.flipResult ? (
          <div>
            The result is {this.state.flipResult}.
            <br />
            <br />
            <img
              src={`./img/${this.state.coinURL}.jpg`}
              alt="coin"
              style={{ width: "200px", height: "auto" }}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div> No result yet! </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### What Have I done

as updating a state is an async process so we can make the parent function async and wait for updating state by `await` command