# Can't seem to update my GET request data, what am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I have this function:

```
const getPlayerData = async (playerId) => {
        await ligaApi.get(`/players/${playerId}`).then((res) => {
            console.log('getPlayerData',res.data);
                 //setPlayers(res.data)? not working
        });
```

That is getting called inside this function:

```
const getTeamById = useCallback(async (teamId) => {
    await ligaApi.get(`/teams/${teamId}/players`).then((res) => {
        const response = res.data;
        const getPlayerDataRequests = response?.map((x) => x.playerId);

        Promise.all(getPlayerDataRequests).then((res) => {
            console.log('RES',res)
            
            for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                const playerData = res[i];
            --> getPlayerData(playerData);
            
            }
        });
    });
}, []);
```

So in my GET request, I get 3 different object arrays.

```
{ id: 1373, firstName: 'homer', lastName: 'simpson', email: 'homer.simpson@gmail.com', run: '1235457', …}
    {id: 1595, firstName: 'Jebediah', lastName: 'Springfield', email: 'Jebediah@springfield.com', run: '11111111-1', …}
    {id: 4002, firstName: 'Jugador', lastName: 'De Prueba', email: 'a946657@trbvm.com', run: '5405844-6', …}
```

The thing is I want to update the state:

```
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
```

And when I update the state inside `getPlayerData` my Web page breaks. My end goal is to map the info through a card list component passing the state as prop but can't seem to get it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the spread operator as mentioned in this post for arrays in useState: [useState on React Hooks not updating Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291964/usestate-on-react-hooks-not-updating-array)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You've wrapped `Promise.all()` around the wrong set of data.

After retrieving the array of player IDs, you should map the IDs to an array of promises, ie the results from `getPlayerData(playerId)`. Then you can use `Promise.all()` to wait for those to resolve

```js
// define these outside your component rather than using `useCallback`
const getPlayerData = async (playerId) =>
  (await ligaApi.get(`/players/${playerId}`)).data;

export const getTeamById = async (teamId) => {
  const { data } = await ligaApi.get(`/teams/${teamId}/players`);
  return Promise.all(data.map(({ playerId }) => getPlayerData(playerId)));
};
```

Then in your component, you can simply use this in an effect hook

```js
getTeamById(teamId).then(setPlayers).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up updating state like this:

```
setPlayers((prevState)=>[...prevState, response]);
```

So thank you Skar, I could understant better